# Protect hidden fields on browser console?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to use javascript to protect hidden fields to be edited by the user using the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

No. Anything client-side can be manipulated. The solution is to validate input server-side.

Comment: And use session variables for data you need to pass from one page to the next securely.